# Error in saving rdd to cassandra table: NoSuchElementException: key not found

Tags: apache-spark, cassandra, apache-kafka, spark-streaming, spark-cassandra-connector

I am trying to save rdd to cassandra table but getting this error.  Can some tell me where I am doing wrong.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException: key not found: date

18/03/26 05:35:39 INFO CassandraConnector: Disconnected from Cassandra cluster: Test Cluster
```

My spark code is

```
val lines = KafkaUtils.createStream(ssc, "localhost:2181", "spark-streaming-consumer-group", Map("hello" -> 5))
val cass=sparkConf.set("spark.cassandra.connection.host","127.0.1.1")
val data=lines.map(_._2)
  val ndata=data.map(Tuple1())
ndata.saveToCassandra("mydata","stations")
```

data rdd is like

```
{"id":"04bBGJpwUh","date":"2018-03-26 05:28:25","temp":37,"press":16}
{"id":"pi4Axn3iOd","date":"2018-03-26 05:28:27","temp":49,"press":17}
```

Cassandra table is

```
CREATE TABLE mydata.stations(id text primary key,date text,temp int,press int);
```

Comment: Without a closer look: date is a reserved keyword in cassandra - that might cause trouble.

Comment: @TobiSH Even after changing the name error is still same like key not found: tdate